# Comparing readonly value with a value entered by a user

Tags: javascript, html

I have table which have available quantity value of a `readonly` and a quantity entered by a user. I check if the available quantity is more than what the user entered. If value entered by user is more than available quantity I tell the user to enter value less than available quantity. The first entered quantity value gets validated correctly. I get problem when the user enter second quantity. How can I tackle this? I use `availableQuantity` and `quantity` as my `id's`

Here is my code HTML

```
<div id="makeOrders">
    <table id="myDatatable" class="display datatable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Part No</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Model No</th>
                <th>Available QTY</th>
                <th>Tick To Order</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <!-- <th>Edit</th> -->
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <!-- Iterating over the list sent from Controller -->
            <c:forEach var="list" items="${compatibility}">

                <tr>
                    <td>${list.partNumber}</td>
                    <td>${list.itemDescription}</td>
                    <td>${list.compitableDevice}</td>
                    <td><input type="number" id="avaliableQuantity"
                        name="avaliableQuantity" class="form-control" readonly="readonly"
                        value="${list.quantity}"></td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" class="form-group"
                        id="checkedOrder" name="selectedItem"
                        value="${list.partNumber},${list.compitableDevice},${list.itemDescription}"></td>
                    <td><input type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity"
                        class="form-control" onblur="compareQuantity()" value="" /></td>
                </tr>

            </c:forEach>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</div>
```

This my JavaScript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        /*Compare available quantity with entered quantity*/
        function compareQuantity() {

            var ourAvaliableQuantity = document.getElementById("avaliableQuantity").value; 
            var yourQuantity = document.getElementById("quantity").value;           
            if ( ourAvaliableQuantity  > yourQuantity ) {
                alert("Your quantity (" +yourQuantity+ ") is less or equal to available quantity (" + ourAvaliableQuantity+ ") order.\n You can now place your order"); 
                console.log("True,",yourQuantity + " is less than " + ourAvaliableQuantity);
                console.log("Place an Order");
            }else if(ourAvaliableQuantity < yourQuantity) {
                alert("Your order quantity (" +yourQuantity+ ") can not be greater than available quantity (" + ourAvaliableQuantity+ "). \n Please enter less quantity");
                document.getElementById("quantity").value = "";
                console.log("False,",ourAvaliableQuantity + " is small than " + yourQuantity);
                console.log("You can not place an order, enter less quantity");
                console.log("Enter value between 1 till " +ourAvaliableQuantity+ " not more than " +ourAvaliableQuantity);
            } 
        } 
</script>
```

Comment: Just curious, what's the point of comparing a read only value? You do realise that a user can simply edit the readonly value if they want to.

Comment: You're comparing strings, doing `>=` etc. doesn't always do what you think it does, for instance `"2" > "10"` is truthy

Comment: @adeneo I can change my `type="text"` to `type="number"` to restrict user to enter strings.

Comment: @A.Lau there is a reason I made the available quantity to be a readonly. How would user change a readonly value?

Comment: html/javascript is generated on client side. Just go to your webpage, right click your `readonly` element. Hit `inspect` and then just remove the `readonly` part from it and you can edit it. I'm only asking since you're probably I'm assuming you're not going to validate the user input server side

Comment: I used readonly because when I use disabled I don't get the available Quantity when I submit my form.

Comment: like I said, the users can edit that readonly, regardless if it's disabled or set to `readonly` so having it there is pointless unless it's an indicator to the user. You will still need to do server-side checking, unless you don't malicious/curious people breaking your website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The id attribute specifies a unique id for an HTML element, it must must be unique within the HTML document. try use the id concatenating an unique value from the 'list' variable. Or pass the '${list.quantity}' to the function.

```
       <c:forEach var="list" items="${compatibility}">

            <tr>
                <td>${list.partNumber}</td>
                <td>${list.itemDescription}</td>
                <td>${list.compitableDevice}</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="${list.partNumber}_avaliableQuantity"
                    name="avaliableQuantity" class="form-control" readonly="readonly"
                    value="${list.quantity}"></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" class="form-group"
                    id="checkedOrder" name="selectedItem"
                    value="${list.partNumber},${list.compitableDevice},${list.itemDescription}"></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="${list.partNumber}_quantity" name="quantity"
                    class="form-control" onblur="compareQuantity(this, ${list.quantity})" value="" /></td>
            </tr>

        </c:forEach>
```

And in your javascript

```
function compareQuantity(element, availableQuantity) {
  if (availableQuantity >= element.value){
....
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works. But when I want to remove the quantity in the text box if its bigger than available quantity it says `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null`. I use this line to remove quantity `document.getElementById(element.value).value = "";`

Comment: you are passing the element, so can use: 
**element.value = null**.   Remember that the id is not 'quantity', the correc id is the generated with id="${list.partNumber}_quantity".

Comment: Okay thanks a lot this was very helpful and it was what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You may only have one ID per page. Develop a name scheme such that you don't have two or more `id="availableQuantity"` or `id="quantity"` on the page.  For instance:

```
<tr>
  <td>${list.partNumber}</td>
  <td>${list.itemDescription}</td>
  <td>${list.compitableDevice}</td>
  <td><input type="text" id="avaliableQuantity-1" name="avaliableQuantity" class="form-control" readonly="readonly" value="${list.quantity}"></td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" class="form-group" id="checkedOrder" name="selectedItem" value="${list.partNumber},${list.compitableDevice},${list.itemDescription}"></td>
  <td><input type="text" id="quantity-1" name="quantity" class="form-control" onblur="compareQuantity()" value="" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>${list.partNumber}</td>
  <td>${list.itemDescription}</td>
  <td>${list.compitableDevice}</td>
  <td><input type="text" id="avaliableQuantity-2" name="avaliableQuantity" class="form-control" readonly="readonly" value="${list.quantity}"></td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" class="form-group" id="checkedOrder" name="selectedItem" value="${list.partNumber},${list.compitableDevice},${list.itemDescription}"></td>
  <td><input type="text" id="quantity-2" name="quantity" class="form-control" onblur="compareQuantity()" value="" /></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I know I can have only one `id` per page. And `id` is not reusable

Comment: @King people reading your question don't know that, please update your question with an actual example and not server-side code.

Answer (score 0):

1) A document should only have one element with each ID, so maybe you want to use classes or `data-` attributes to find the available quantity. For example, you could add 'data-available-quantity' on the element, and then you can just check this with `this.dataset.availableQuantity`.

2) You don't need to look up the element because you can just pass it when onBlur is called, like

```
<input type="text" onblur="checkQuantity(this)" data-available-quantity="25" name="quantity" ...
```

and then your function looks like

```
function checkQuantity(element) {
  if (parseInt(element.dataset.availableQuantity) < parseInt(element.value()))
    // this is where you add a message
```

(edit: added parseInt to make sure they're all integers)

Comment: I get `Uncaught TypeError: element.value is not a function` when trying to use this.

Comment: sorry it's element.value not value()

Comment: while this doesn't strictly answer your question of 'how do I use a readonly value', using data attributes is cleaner in my opinion.