# Include in a SSL site in iframe an non SSL site and view it normal

Tags: wordpress, ssl, iframe

I try to add in a SSL wordpress site an iframe from an external wordpress site with src http://external.com/ but the website is not loading in the iframe.
At first time i show that the http was replaced auto by https. I added a filter to not allow replace this but again the site is not loading inside the iframe.

I have try with php too but the same happends. Not loading the URL.

```
<?php echo file_get_contents('http://external.com/api.php'); ?>
```

The api.php content is a iframe with random permalink from wordpress posts.
I dont use the php method in iframe src. Dont be confused about that.

Is the anyway to make it working?

thank you

Comment: Take a look to this link related to your question:
[How to allow http content within an iframe on a https site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43035420/comparing-readonly-value-with-a-value-entered-by-a-user)

Comment: i 'm not sure about your link but is showing something from the title.

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer about '[How to allow http content within an iframe on a https site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18327314/how-to-allow-http-content-within-an-iframe-on-a-https-site)'. In which the solution proposed is to make a redirect using google or creating your own redirect script on an https page that you control.

I made this reference earlier but with a wrong link, sorry.